# JQuery click event is not working in Safari windows 7

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<button id="add" >Add</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#add").click(function () {
                alert("hi");
            });
```

This function is working in iPad safari but not working in windows safari.

Comment: Please check below link.
http://jquery.com/browser-support/
**If you need to support older browsers like Internet Explorer 6-8, Opera 12.1x or Safari 5.1+, use jQuery 1.12.**
Also add some details, in your question related to which version of JQuery used etc.

Comment: Is the jQuery code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @ Barmar no it is not inside $(document).ready(), both way i tried with and without $(document).ready() ..its not working

Comment: @GauravKP safari version 5.1.7, jQuery 1.7.1

Answer (score 1):

The DOM must be ready. Either link the script after creating the button.
or use jquery to run the snippet after the DOM is ready.

```
<button>
<script>...</script>
```

> I would use the `ready()`

**HTML:**

```
<button id="add" >Add</button>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function () {
        alert("hi");
    });
});
```

Comment: it is not working , i have done like as you said. could you please tell some other method for it.

Comment: check the console if you have any errors. post it here

Comment: `<button onClick="addFunction()">Add</button> function addFunction(){
           alert("1");}` this is working , but using id attribute ,function is not triggering

Answer (score 0):

Below code works on **Safari For Windows Version 5.1.7** with **JQuery 1.7.1**. This is a basic functionality, so I do not see any issue with JavaScript code.

Also in one of your comment you had mentioned that `<button onClick="addFunction()">Add</button> function addFunction(){ alert("1");}` is working. This is because it is not using JQuery, so I think you need to check that JQuery is properly loaded before the function is called. Try to open the page in FireFox/ Chrome Developer Console, and check if you are getting any error related to JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="add">Add</button>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#add").click(function () {
            alert("hi");
        });
    </script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: yes i have checked in IE, Chrome and Firefox, its working perfectly, but not working in safari